# Kendo grid Title attribute format

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, formatting, kendo-grid, decimalformat

I am trying to format my title/tootlip attribute to a format of `"0000.0000"`(show 4 decimal points), which is currently eliminating zero values after decimal point.

I tried with following code,

`columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice)
        .Title("*Unit Price")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @title = "#= kendo.toString(UnitPrice,\"n4\"); #", style = "text-align:right" })
        .Format("{0:n4}").Width("8%");`

Comment: is this the kind of thing you are after: https://dojo.telerik.com/IJuQUpAJ (i have added the tooltip on the Frieght 2 Field)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i have handled it by adding a kendo tooltip. it is now working fine.